# Android - size of compressed and uncompressed images the same

Tags: android, bitmap, compression

I am trying to compress an image and output the size of the compressed and original images to Logcat (using `Bitmap.getAllocationByteCount()`). However, the compressed and original image sizes are always the same despite a visible change in the compressed image's quality. I am making use of the Picasso SDK to read images from a resource and eventually load a bitmap returned by the callback in the `Target` class into an `ImageView`.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ImageView imageView1;
private Target target;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_1);

    target = new Target(){

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

            Log.v("BITMAP BEFORE",Integer.valueOf(bitmap.getAllocationByteCount()).toString());

            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,0,outputStream);

            Bitmap decodedMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray()));

            imageView1.setImageBitmap(decodedMap);

            Log.v("BITMAP AFTER",Integer.valueOf(decodedMap.getAllocationByteCount()).toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

            Log.v("ON BITMAP FAILED", "ON BITMAP FAILED");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            Log.v("ON PREPARE LOAD","ON PREPARE LOAD");
        }
    };

    loadImage();
}


private void loadImage(){

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.smiley).into(target);
}
}
```

I tried compressing JPEGs and PNG with a 0 compression factor, however the sizes are always the same. What am I doing wrong ? An explanation or even a solution would be most appreciated. I am trying to reduce the size of the Bitmap before loading it into an `ImageView`. Thanks in advance.

Edit: 
I tried using `getByteCount()` and `getRowBytes() * getHeight()` in place of getAllocationByteCount() and the results are always the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, the compressed and original image sizes are always the same despite a visible change in the compressed image's quality.

The size in RAM of a `Bitmap` has nothing do to with whether the image is compressed or the image quality. It depends solely on resolution (width, height) and bit depth. `getAllocationByteCount()` returns the size in RAM of the `Bitmap`.

Compression and image quality affect the size **on disk** of a bitmap image.

Comment: Can we determine the compressed storage space, without actually writing the compressed image to the storage.? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6424680/6420004) answer satisfies my requirement but takes up extra RAM.

Comment: @shubhamsharma: I do not know of any way to predict how well compression will work, except to actually perform the compression.