# Get Image size (storage size) from bitmap

Tags: android, arrays, image, file, bitmap

I'm reading an image from my phone storage. Among other things, I want to get the size (size in storage, not dimens) of that image.

I know that there are many questions about the topic like:

[How to get the size of an image in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316986/how-to-get-the-size-of-an-image-in-android)

[how to check image size less then 100kb android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137003/how-to-check-image-size-less-then-100kb-android)

[Is there any way to get the storage size of a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424410/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-storage-size-of-a-bitmap)

...

But none of those gives me the correct size of the image.

Having the `imageUri`, I convert it to a bitmap as follows:

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(activity.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
```

And then I try:

```
bitmap.getByteCount()
```

For a specific image, that I know that it is **1.20MB**, the line above returns the value of **9216000**. Since it is in `Bytes`, dividing it by **1024 * 1024**, will return **8.78MB**.

It clearly doesn't correspond to the real size.

Has anyone else experienced the same trouble?

**Notes**:

1. The solutions should only consider that the size should be extracted from the `Bitmap` object (not `File` or something else...)
2. Tried with `png` and `jpg` images

Comment: Maybe I found a answer for you. This has been asked already.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31694333/8301375

Comment: `I want to get the size (size in storage, not dimens) of that image.`. It looks as if you want to know the filesize of the file in storage. `The solutions should only consider that the size should be extracted from the Bitmap object` Well that is something quite differen and not according to what you said first.